# RESPONSIVE THEME: Keep "text" fixed in the picture (html, css)

Tags: jquery, html, css, shopify

I am editing a shopify Responsive theme. But I am facing a problem with homepage main banner 1800x700. Whenever I zoom-in the picture the text also zooms-in... so on mobile, the text is HUGE and coverts the banner in whole.

I want to keep the text fixed. One way is to add a text in photoshop it will be fixed. But it's a last resort
But the thing is, the text is added on top of the picture via shopify admin panel.

Comment: can you show us the code please?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your text less with [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). For example for display less than `600px` the media will be: `@media (max-width: 600px)`.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/8gfdabja/) is code example:

```css
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    h1 {
        font-size: 24px;
    }
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello world!</h1>
```